# `pip` is missing python 3.4.3, PyCharm IDE

Tags: python, pip

I just installed python 3.4.3 and pyCharm 4.5, while installing module six. I got the following error message. I thought `pip` is included in python 3.4.3 installation. Any suggestions?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 4.5.3\helpers\packaging_tool.py", line 56, in do_install
    import pip
ImportError: No module named 'pip'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 4.5.3\helpers\packaging_tool.py", line 125, in main
    retcode = do_install(pkgs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 4.5.3\helpers\packaging_tool.py", line 58, in do_install
    error_no_pip()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 4.5.3\helpers\packaging_tool.py", line 36, in error_no_pip
    tb = sys.exc_traceback
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'exc_traceback'
```

**UPDATE:**

Okay, following suggestion below, I checked that there is no pip.exe on hard drive. So I downloaded get-pip.py and tried to install it. Here is the error message:

```
C:\Python34>python get-pip.py
Collecting pip
  Using cached pip-7.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting wheel
  Using cached wheel-0.24.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pip, wheel
  Found existing installation: pip 6.0.8
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\somepath\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpram2_j5v\pip.zip\pip\basecommand
.py", line 223, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Users\somepath\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpram2_j5v\pip.zip\pip\commands\in
stall.py", line 299, in run
    root=options.root_path,
  File "C:\Users\somepath\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpram2_j5v\pip.zip\pip\req\req_set
.py", line 640, in install
    requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
  File "C:\Users\somepath\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpram2_j5v\pip.zip\pip\req\req_ins
tall.py", line 683, in uninstall
    for path in pip.wheel.uninstallation_paths(dist):
  File "C:\Users\somepath\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpram2_j5v\pip.zip\pip\wheel.py",
line 512, in unique
    for item in fn(*args, **kw):
  File "C:\Users\somepath\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpram2_j5v\pip.zip\pip\wheel.py",
line 531, in uninstallation_paths
    r = csv.reader(FakeFile(dist.get_metadata_lines('RECORD')))
  File "C:\Users\somepath\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpram2_j5v\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\pkg
_resources\__init__.py", line 1619, in get_metadata_lines
    return yield_lines(self.get_metadata(name))
  File "C:\Users\somepath\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpram2_j5v\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\pkg
_resources\__init__.py", line 1616, in get_metadata
    return self._get(self._fn(self.egg_info, name)).decode("utf-8")
  File "C:\Users\somepath\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpram2_j5v\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\pkg
_resources\__init__.py", line 1722, in _get
    with open(path, 'rb') as stream:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\\python34\\lib\\site
-packages\\pip-6.0.8.dist-info\\RECORD'
```

**FINAL UPDATE:**

Uninstalling Python and deleting C:\Python34 folder helped. New installation came with pip. Sorry for all this mess.

Comment: Have you tried `pip3`?

Comment: Could be a path issue, or an issue on JetBrain's side. Search your drive for pip to make sure it exists. If it does, either jetbrains is importing the wrong name (pip3 as @brainlesscoder suggests) or pip is not installed on a path that jetbrains looks for modules on. You are correct that pip is included in python bundles >= 3.4.0